# How can I determine whether a Windows logoff was manual or automated?

Tags: windows, events, logoff

Here are two common ways users can be logged off of Windows:

- **Manual**: The user logs off manually
- **Automated**: The windows system logs off the user automatically via some mechanism

Is there any way to determine (*based on a stock Windows install, with no special software installed*) the method of the logoff?  i.e. which of these two methods (*Manual/Auto*) for logoff were utilized?

Comment: [System Shutdown Reason Codes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/system-shutdown-reason-codes) and [Shutdown Event Tracker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc783475(v=ws.10)) seem like they might be relevant here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When a user invokes a log off/sign out (**manual**) action, this is logged to the Security event log as Event ID **4647**. **Automatic** log off (session timeout) will be logged to the event log as Event ID **4634**.

To review the events in the event log, perform these actions

1. Load `eventvwr` from Start > Run
2. Click on `Security` under the Windows Logs
3. Click `Filter Current Log` on the right-hand actions menu
4. Enter `4634,4647` in the field under `Includes/Excludes Event IDs:`

[image]

Click OK, and you'll see a list of events related to the chosen event ID's.

If you don't see anything, then either your event log has been purged, or the event is too old and you need to change how much data the event viewer stores.

A comprehensive list of event ID's can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/appendix-l--events-to-monitor).

Comment: Just tried this on my Windows 10 Pro 21H2 which has 3 months of security event log and neither of these events is found. Does your answer only apply to Windows Server ?

Comment: My two-day old Win10 21H2 instance has 33 logout events, varied between the two codes (mostly 4634 due to UMFD-X accounts).  You're either not logging, not filtering correctly, or not searching the right log. See https://i.imgur.com/Q7YdFTs.png for a screenshot. Ensure you're filtering the "Windows Logs > Security" log

Comment: @grahamj42 no, my windows 10 laptop on a domain has plenty of events.